# pd.Series of lists to numpy 2d array

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a pd.Series of lists.

i.e. `df = pd.Series([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']])`

I'd like to convert it to a 2d numpy array.

Doing this: `np.array(df.values)` doesn't yield the desired result, as the list is considered as an object.

How to get a 2d array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your solution only convert values to lists:

```
print (np.array(df.values.tolist()))
[['a' 'b']
 ['c' 'd']]
```

Or create `DataFrame` first:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(df.values.tolist()).values)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this solution appears to be slightly faster than the one from @yaseco using a small test dataset. `%%timeit` results: 

`np.array(df.values.tolist())`: 683 µs ± 20 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
`np.stack(df.values)`: 759 µs ± 50.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Answer (score 1):

Just apply `pd.Series`:

```
df.apply(pd.Series).values
```

Comment: Check last statement - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35491399/2901002

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just found `np.stack` can do that too.

```
df = pd.Series([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']])
np.stack(df.values).shape
```

results

> (2, 2)